# FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Invalid role assignment.: []

Tags: apex, unit-test, roles, field-integrity-exception

I am building some test data in my unit test.

Roughly I have something like this:

```
@IsTest
static void getUserTest() {
    Account acct = new Account();
    acct.Name = 'Test Account';
    insert acct;

    Contact contact = new Contact();
    contact.LastName = 'Test';
    contact.FirstName = 'Test';
    contact.accountId = acct.Id;
    insert contact;

    User adminUser = new User();
    adminUser.FirstName = 'Test';
    adminUser.LastName = 'Test';
    adminUser.Alias = 'Test';
    adminUser.Email = 'someemail@blabla.com';
    adminUser.UserName = 'someemail@blabla.com';
    adminUser.EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
    adminUser.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
    adminUser.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
    adminUser.TimezoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles';
    adminUser.ProfileId = [
                SELECT Id
                FROM Profile
                WHERE Name = 'System Administrator'
        ].Id;
    insert adminUser;

    UserRole userRole = [SELECT Id FROM UserRole WHERE PortalType = 'CustomerPortal' LIMIT 1];

    User testUser;
    System.runAs(adminUser) {
        testUser = new User();
        testUser.FirstName = 'Test2';
        testUser.LastName = 'Test2';
        testUser.Alias = 'Test2';
        testUser.Email = 'someotheremail@blabla.com';
        testUser.UserName = 'someotheremail@blabla.com';
        testUser.EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
        testUser.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
        testUser.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
        testUser.TimezoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles';
        testUser.ContactId = contact.Id;
        testUser.ProfileId = [
                        SELECT Id
                        FROM Profile
                        WHERE Name = 'Customer Self Service Community Profile'
                        ].Id;
        testUser.UserRoleId = userRole.Id;
        insert testUser;
    }
}
```

The `insert testUser` line gives me the following error:

```
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; 
first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Invalid role assignment.: []
```

The above code is working correctly in one sandbox but fails in another. Both sandboxes are super out of sync(out of my control). Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `Customer Selft Service Community Profile` ?? Typo?

Comment: @cropredy Thanks for pointing that out but that's not the problem(unfortunately). I guess I put the `t` in the code snippet as I was copying it out of the class in question. Sorry about that.

Comment: Are you not creating an Account here?

Comment: @JayantDas Sorry missed adding this to my code snippet. I have an account and still get the same error.

Comment: Okay so do you have a role assigned for the account owner? That seems to be the case here.

Comment: @JayantDas That's what I am trying to do at `testUser.UserRoleId = userRole.Id;` That's also what is failing. Unless I am misunderstanding your question?

Comment: So here’s how it works. That one is where you are creating the portal user (you don’t need a role unless required). What you will need to ensure is that the OwnerId of the Account here has a role assigned. In this case it will be most likely the `adminUser` where you assign a role to that user while creating and then use `acct.OwnerId=adminUser.Id`. Finally create the portal user.

Comment: @JayantDas I will give it a try, thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You a have to assign the role to `adminUser` as well. Also, the sequence of steps also needs to be changed. Sequence should be as follows

- Create `adminUser` with the role assigned to this user (This `role` should be other than the `customer portal role`).
- Create `Account` and `Contact` while running in `adminUser` context i.e. enclose your `Account` and `Contact` creation code within `system.runAs(adminUser)`. This is because, the `Owner` of the `Account` should have a `role`.
- Create `Community User` as `adminUser` i.e. after creating `Account` and `Contact`, your code for `Community User` creation should follow which should be within `system.runAs(adminUser)`. You can assign PortalRole for this user or can leave it blank, when this field is left blank and a Contact is assigned, the user is automatically assigned a User Role.

Excerpt from Salesforce [User](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_user.htm) documentation

> **PortalRole**
>
> The role of the user in the Customer Portal (either Executive,
> Manager, User, or PersonAcount). Prior to API version 16.0,
> you could set this field to null and the system automatically included
> a portal role. In API version 16.0 and above, when you set this field
> to null, a portal role is not automatically created. When this field
> is null and a ContactId is provided, the user is assigned to the User
> role.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but get this error `FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, role type must match user type`. I guess it's because the user is a system admin but I am trying to assign a `CustomerPortal` role to it.

Comment: Yes, you answered your question. Assign a  role other than customer portal role to system admin and then give a try.

Comment: I still get the same error `Invalid role assignment.: []`. Could it have something to do with communities being inactive? Can the unit test code see the communities?

Comment: Assign role only to `adminUser` and don't assign any role to community user

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly it. It appears that it assigns the role automatically I think.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
    RecordType rt = [Select Id From RecordType Where DeveloperName = 'Staff' limit 1];
    RecordType accountRT = [Select Id From RecordType Where DeveloperName = 'organization' limit 1];
    UserRole r1 = [SELECT Id FROM UserRole WHERE DeveloperName = 'YourUserRole' limit 1];
    Profile portalProfile = [Select Id from Profile where name = 'Your Operator Portal User'];
    Contact portalContact;
    
    User thisUser = new User(Id=UserInfo.getUserId());
    thisUser.UserRoleId = r1.Id;
    update thisUser;
    System.runAs(thisUser) {
        Account portalAccount = new Account(name = 'portalAccount',RecordTypeId=accountRT.Id);//create a portal account first
        insert portalAccount;
        portalContact = new contact(LastName = 'portalContact', AccountId = portalAccount.Id,RecordTypeId = rt.Id); //create a portal contact
        insert portalContact;
    }
    User u1 = new User( email='test@test.com',
                        profileid = portalProfile.Id, 
                        UserName='portalUser@portalTestUser.com', 
                        Alias = 'a',
                        TimeZoneSidKey='Australia/Sydney',
                        EmailEncodingKey='ISO-8859-1',
                        LocaleSidKey='en_US', 
                        LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
                        ContactId = portalContact.Id,
                        FirstName = 'Test FirstName',
                        LastName = 'LastName'
                      );
    
    insert u1;
```

Hope this helps!
If this helps kindly mark it as solved so that it may help others in future.

Thanks,
Parmanand